# getting php-ews to work

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

Downloaded php-ews from https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews and did a

```
            require_once ($server_path."/scripts/ews/API.php");
```

which seems to work (log gives no error).

But doing this:

```
            $ews = ExchangeWebServices::fromUsernameAndPassword($exchange_host, $_SESSION["user_data"]["u_email"], $_SESSION["user_data"]["u_pwd"], $options = array());
```

gives a

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ExchangeWebServices' not found
```

Any one have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd like to suggest you try installing my library with Composer. You can [download it here](https://getcomposer.org/). Then, once installed, you can install my library using it. Just create a `composer.json` file with the following

```
{
    "require": {
        "garethp/php-ews": "0.8.*"
    }
}
```

Then run a `composer install` in the directory. This should create a `vendor/` folder with a `vendor/autoload.php` file. Include this file, and the rest of the classes should be autoloaded

Comment: Ok, I tried composer .. and seems it works (well, it does ;-))
But I still get this:
**(mod_fastcgi.c.2695) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ExchangeWebServices' not found in **

Comment: and the autoloader seems to work. Or atleast when I remove a part of the path it fails loud and clearly ;-)

Comment: `code`echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_declared_classes());
echo "</pre>";`code`
gives  [372] => ComposerAutoloaderInitbc25b4c7c627f48ed3a0f739e38bad53
    [373] => Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
    [374] => Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitbc25b4c7c627f48ed3a0f739e38bad53 but no ews class (API or ExchangeWebServices)

Comment: Have you added your use statement?

Comment: Tried use garethp\ews; -> error "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in"

Comment: Well... yes, you can't use `use` statements in an `if` statement. You can, however, choose to only instantiate the object in an `if` statement. If you have a `use` statement, but don't do anything with it, the file won't be loaded in, so don't worry about it

Answer (score 1):

Made it work by removing my check if the exchange option was valid.

Removed

```
if ($core_row["exchange_active"] == 1) {
```

which were surrounding the api call.

```
require 'scripts/ews/vendor/autoload.php';

$exchange_host = $core_row["exchange_host"].":".$core_row["exchange_port"];
$version = "Exchange2013"; // to be optional in core_data
//Create and build the client
use garethp\ews\API;
$ews = API::withUsernameAndPassword($exchange_host, $_SESSION["user_data"]["u_email"], $_SESSION["user_data"]["u_pwd"], $version);
```

Mad my day a little brighter..

Result of

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r(get_declared_classes()); echo "</pre>";
......

[358] => ComposerAutoloaderInitbc25b4c7c627f48ed3a0f739e38bad53
[359] => Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
[360] => Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitbc25b4c7c627f48ed3a0f739e38bad53
[361] => garethp\ews\API
[362] => garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices
[363] => garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServicesAuth
[364] => garethp\ews\API\ClassMap
[365] => garethp\ews\API\NTLMSoapClient
[366] => garethp\ews\HttpPlayback\HttpPlayback
```

Comment: Just FYI: It's considered good practice to have `require_once` instead, to having nothing else above it, and to have all of your `use` statements right under it. `use` statements should come before any and all logic